# How to insert image to mysql database in netbeans java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have poor knowledge about programming. I need to save image in MySQL database. I have created a database table and there is a column to add image with longblob data type. 
I have code to a button to choose image from folder in PC then it load to a jlable. Now I need to insert this image to a database.

This is my code;

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser(); 
    fc.showOpenDialog(this); 
    File f=fc.getSelectedFile(); 
    String path=f.getAbsolutePath(); 
    jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path)); 

    try{ 
        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(f); 
        int len=(int)f.length(); Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:my­sql://localhost/hss", "root", "bis123"); 
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("Insert into profile values(?)"); 

        ps.setBinaryStream(1, fin, len); 
        int status=ps.executeUpdate(); 

        if(status > 0) { 
            jLabel2.setText("Successfully inserted in DB"); 
        }else{ 
            jLabel2.setText("Image not inserted!"); 
        } 
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In MySQL when we use the blob type to store the data , it support only 5 kb image capacity.**

CREATE TABLE `image` (

`id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,

`size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

`image` longblob

);

created database table in above code

this is java code to insert image in database

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
public class InsertImagesMysql{
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Insert Image Example!");
    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "test";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "root";
    Connection con = null;
    try{
       Class.forName(driverName);
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
       Statement st = con.createStatement();
       File imgfile = new File("pic.jpg");

      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(imgfile);

       PreparedStatement pre =
       con.prepareStatement("insert into Image values(?,?,?)");

       pre.setString(1,"test");
       pre.setInt(2,3);
       pre.setBinaryStream(3,(InputStream)fin,(int)imgfile.length());
       pre.executeUpdate();
       System.out.println("Successfully inserted the file into the database!");

       pre.close();
       con.close(); 
    }catch (Exception e1){
        System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
    }
}
    }
```

here is code to retrieve data from database

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class RetriveImagesMysql{
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Retrive Image Example!");
    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "test";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "root";
    Connection con = null;
    try{
        Class.forName(driverName);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select image from image");
        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            InputStream in = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
            OutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("test"+i+".jpg"));
            i++;
            int c = 0;
            while ((c = in.read()) > -1) {
                f.write(c);
            }
            f.close();
            in.close();
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
  }
```

here just assign fin to jbutton action event it will trigger automatically the run of the code

Comment: Thank you Smash. I will try this.